OpenWeatherMap Trigger API not producing alerts
Checking in here to see if anyone can get OpenWeatherMap "Trigger" API to produce an alert. I cannot. (verified with conditions for the location transitioning over the trigger boundary and yet no alert appears)
This is what I started with
{
   "time_period":{
      "start":{
         "expression":"after",
         "amount":1000
      },
      "end":{
         "expression":"after",
         "amount":7200000
      }
   },
   "conditions":[
      {
         "name":"temp",
         "expression":"$gt",
         "amount":299
      }
   ],
   "area":[
      {
         "type":"Point",
         "coordinates":[
            35,
            -82
         ]
      }
   ]
}

For that locale the temperature over the past hour or so has gone from 295 to 301. And yet, there's still no alert
{
  "_id": [REDACTED],
  "__v": 0,
  "alerts": {},      <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  "area": [
    {
      "type": "Point",
      "_id": [REDACTED],
      "coordinates": [
        35,
        -82
      ]
    }
  ],
  "conditions": [
    {
      "name": "temp",
      "expression": "$gt",
      "amount": 299,
      "_id": [REDACTED]
    }
  ],
  "time_period": {
    "end": {
      "expression": "after",
      "amount": 7200000
    },
    "start": {
      "expression": "after",
      "amount": 1000
    }
  }
}

Can anyone shed some light on this? I've reached out to the folks at OpenWeatherMap dot org and haven't gotten a response back yet. If someone can confirm that they can get an alert from the API I'd be glad to read about it. Thanks in advance!
